# Is there a possibility to keep column order when reading parquet?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Saving a dataframe with columns (e.g. "a", "b") as parquet and then reading the parquet at later point in time does not deliver the same column order (could be "b", "a" f.e.) as the file was saved with.

Unfortunately, I was not able to figure out, how the order is influenced and how I can control it.

How to keep original column order when reading in parquet?

Answer (score 6):

[PARQUET-188](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-188) suggests that column ordering is not part of the parquet spec, so it's probably not a good idea to rely on the ordering. You could however manage this yourself, e.g. by loading/saving the dataframe columns in lexicographical order, or by storing the column names.

Comment: Thx for the info. Still, I'm irritated as Ryan says "I spoke with Julien about updating the spec and he agreed that the order should match the schema's field order. Parquet Format PR #22 fixes the format." That sounds like the opposite, thus column order gets respected.

Comment: Greetings from 2018... this still doesn't seem to be a respected standard, causing impala to shuffle data around when reading parquets file that happen to have different column ordering