# Do Parquet files preserve column order of Spark DataFrames?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

Does creating a Spark DataFrame and saving it in Parquet format guarantee that the order of columns in the parquet file will be preserved?

Ex) A Spark DataFrame is created with columns A, B, C, and saved as Parquet. When the Parquet files are read, will the column order always be A, B, C?

I've noticed that if I save a Spark DataFrame, and then read the parquet files, the column order is preserved:

```
df.select("A", "B", "C").write.save(...)
df = spark.read.load(...)
df.printSchema()


root
 |-- A: string (nullable = true)
 |-- B: string (nullable = true)
 |-- C: string (nullable = true)
```

Then, if I save by selecting a different order of columns, and then read the parquet files, I can see the order is also what I expect:

```
df.select("C", "B", "A").write.save(...)
df = spark.read.load(...)
df.printSchema()

root
 |-- C: string (nullable = true)
 |-- B: string (nullable = true)
 |-- A: string (nullable = true)
```

However, I can't seem to find any documentation supporting this, and the comments of this post: [Is there a possibility to keep column order when reading parquet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748478/is-there-a-possibility-to-keep-column-order-when-reading-parquet) have conflicting information.

Comment: I have never experienced the column of parquet files are shuffled.